# Setting up my Hangman methods and calling them in my main method

Tags: java, oop, methods, program-entry-point

Having difficulty calling the methods in my Game class to my main method for my hangman game. 
We're supposed to spin a wheel to get a jackpot amount for 100,250 or 500 bucks then play the game as you'd expect... But methods are a necessity. Im nowhere near done I just want to be able to call my methods at this point to see how its working.
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] songs = {"asdnj", "satisfaction", "mr jones",
        "uptown funk"}; //note this is a very short list as an example 
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i = rand.nextInt(songs.length);
        String secretword = songs[i];
        System.out.print("Welcome to The Guessing Game. The topic is song      titles. \nYou have 6 guesses. Your puzzle has the following letters: ");
        System.out.print("After spinning the wheel, you got " + spinWheel());

        //continue the code here.
    }
}

class Game {
    Random rand = new Random();
    String[] songs = {"asdnj", "satisfaction", "mr jones",
    "uptown funk"};
    int i = rand.nextInt(songs.length);
    private String secretword = songs[i];
    private char [] charSongs = secretword.toCharArray();
    private char [] guessed = new char [charSongs.length];
    private int guesses;
    private int misses; 
    private char letter;
    private char [] jackpotAmount = {100,250,500};

    public Game (){}

    public int spinWheel(int[] jackpotAmount){
      int rand = new Random().nextInt(jackpotAmount.length);
      return jackpotAmount[rand];
    }

    public char guessLetter(char charSongs [], char letter){
        int timesFound = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < charSongs.length; i++){
           if (charSongs[i] == letter){
             timesFound++;
             guessed[i] = letter;
           }
        }
        return letter;
    }
}
```

And the return error is

> GameDemo.java:11: error: cannot find symbol System.out.print("After
>   spinning the wheel, you got " + spinWheel()); ^

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: Sorry. I have errors in my main method when im calling the spinWheel method. Not sure what I did wrong

Comment: and those errors are...?

Comment: GameDemo.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
 System.out.print("After spinning the wheel, you got " + spinWheel());
                                                                                        ^

Comment: "symbol" pointing at spinWheel

Comment: spinwheel is a method in your game object, but you're calling it as a toplevel function in the gamedemo function, so it doesn't exist there.

Comment: So what would be the correct way to call it?

Answer (score 0):

To call methods from another class you need to make the method `public`. Once that is done, make them `static` if you will call the same method many times and you want it do the same function each time (the parameters can still be different).

To call the method do the following (this is a general form for most classes and methods, you should be able to use this to call all your methods):

```
yourClassWithMethod.methodName();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your `spinWheel`method call:

1. You haven't instantiated any any `Game` object to call this method. Either you have to make it [`static`](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program)  or just instantiate a `Game` and call it from that objet. I personally prefer the second (non-static) option because, especially because a static method cannot access directly non-static method or variables (... you need an instance or to make them `static`).

In main, you can do this (non-static solution):

```
Game game = new Game();
System.out.print("After spinning the wheel, you got " + game.spinWheel());
```

2. `spinWheel` requires an argument of type `int[]`. It seems that it is not useful  since there is an instance variable `jackpotAmount` that seems to have been created on that purpose. `jackpotAmount` (see also second point) should be static in you example.

`spinWheel` becomes :

```
//you can have "public static int spinWheel(){" 
//if you chose the static solution
//Note that jackpotAmount should also be static in that case
public int spinWheel(){
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(jackpotAmount.length);
    return jackpotAmount[rand];
}
```

Note that `jackpotAmount` should better be an `int[]`than a `char[]`